# Detect Linux NTFS symlinks under Windows/WSL

Tags: ntfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, symbolic-link, ntfs-3g, interix

Symlinks created in Linux on NTFS drives (`ln -s`) appear in Windows as short files with contents `IntxLNK + 0x01 + (UTF-16 encoded target path)` -- probably [Interix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix). I want to write a script to convert them, when booting in Windows, to proper NTFS symlinks, using WSL's `ln`. However, I don't know how to detect short files that are really Linux symlinks, except by looking at each file's content, which would suck for a large filesystem, and would fail for plain files starting with the magic.

Why NTFS-3g still cannot create proper reparse points like the Windows `mklink` or WSL2's `ln -s`, even though such Windows symlinks work properly under Linux, and even though `getfattr -n system.ntfs_reparse_data` can read the NTFS symlink data, is beyond me. It should really be just a simple `setfattr`, though I don't know what to put in the attribute.

So, is there a way to detect symlinks created under Linux using file metadata (not contents)? I'm sure the Linux symlinks have some special attributes, because NTFS-3g can distinguish between plain files containing the `InterLnkx` magic and actual symlinks containing the same magic.

Related (no answers): https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/env60r/converting_linux_symlinks_to_windows_symlinks/

[Python script to convert; detection by file contents](https://gist.github.com/Vftdan/31c1a2e0ca2bc1a2c37921a1c99eef26)

Comment: I'm assuming that a `stat` under WSL just shows these as regular files?

Comment: Creation of reparse point-based symlinks was implemented in ntfs-3g two weeks ago. Though it uses the WSL-specific reparse tag, not the native Windows 7–10 symlinks (possibly because those don't exactly match Linux semantics).

Comment: well, the main issue is to have Windows - Linux interoperability at least for symlinks that stay within the drive and link to "real" files/dirs. So that change wouldn't solve it, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out using `ntfsinfo` and comparing two files -- a symlink made from Linux and a copy of the symlink file created in Windows.

It has to be a system file (`ATTRIB +S` on Windows, or use `ntfs_attr.sh` at https://gist.github.com/Explorer09/ac4bf6838c271a9968b3 on Linux). As soon as the system attribute is turned on, NTFS-3g sees the file as a symlink, and if it's turned off, it becomes a plain file. So... on to scripting.

Comment: Ahh, good for you. It still fails on my Win10 even after `ATTRIB +S`. (FTR: FAR Manager shows `LX_SYM` as the file type for those links created by the WSL Debian (12).) I'm not sure if the NTFS driver even sets it as a reparse point (which is unfixable by `ntfs_attr.sh`). Or, actually, wait, it does. So, it's probably that rep. point tag mismatch @u1686_grawity mentioned at the question. Actually, I'm baffled why it worked for you. :-o